# I think my code considers one of my variables higher than the other but can't seem to figure out why?

Tags: python

Basically, I have this code where you choose a number (stored in a var called "chn") and then the program compares it to another randomly chosen number (stored in a var called "rng") and the progtam shows all that on a GUI. It then tells the user if 'chn' is higher or lower than 'rng' but for some reasons if I write :

```
    if chn < rng:
        label2['text'] = 'Too low' 
    elif chn > rng:
        label2['text'] = 'Too high'
    else:
        label2['text'] = 'You won !'
```

it will print 'Too low' no matter the value.

but if I write :

```
    if chn > rng:
        label2['text'] = 'Too low' 
    elif chn < rng:
        label2['text'] = 'Too high'
    else:
        label2['text'] = 'You won !'
```

it will print 'Too high' no matter the value.

**Here is the full code**

```
from random import *
from tkinter import *

rng = str(randint(1, 100))


mf = Tk()
mf.title('Deviner le nombre')
mf.geometry('480x400')
mf.resizable(width=True, height=True)
mf['bg'] = 'white'


label1 = Label(mf, text='Deviner le bon numéro !', fg='Black', bg='white')
label1['font'] = ('Arial', 20)
label1.place(x=85, y=50)

bouton1 = Button(mf, text='Quitter', width=10, height=2, command=mf.destroy)
bouton1.place(x=350, y=300)

chn = str()


entryChn = Entry(mf, textvariable=chn)
entryChn.place(x=180, y=100)


label2 = Label(mf, text='', fg='Red', bg='white')
label2['font'] = ('Arial', 16)
label2.place(x=65, y=150)

chn = str(chn)


def verifier():
    if chn < rng:
        label2['text'] = 'Too low'
    elif chn > rng:
        label2['text'] = 'Too high'
    else:
        label2['text'] = 'You won !'


def effacer():
    label2['text'] = ''


bouton2 = Button(mf, text='Vérifier', width=10, height=2, command=verifier)
bouton2.place(x=80, y=300)

bouton3 = Button(mf, text='Relancer', width=10, height=2, command=effacer)
bouton3.place(x=215, y=300)

mf.mainloop()
```

I tried switching the symbols but it didn't work. I tried assigning defined values to 'chn' and 'rng' but it always gives me an output where 'rng' > 'chn', apart from that everything works well in the code.
I don't know if I'm just oblivious but I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now, please help lol.

Comment: @JohnGordon I now added some lines as following :                                           
entryChn = Entry(mf, textvariable=chn)
entryChn.place(x=180, y=100)
chn_str = entryChn.get()
chn_int = int(chn_str) To try and get the value of entryChn and then turn it into an integer, but it looks like I did something wrong again ? Apparently it's because chn_str doesn't have a value I believe ? (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `chn` should be a `StringVar()` instead of `str()`.
Also, to get value from the `Entry`, it is required to use `chn.get()`.

The content of `chn` is string, string comparison compares strings in lexicographic order, which doesn't work as expected in here. So, it have to be explicitly converted to `int` before comparison.

The code after those changes:

```py
from random import *
from tkinter import *

rng = str(randint(1, 100))


mf = Tk()
mf.title('Deviner le nombre')
mf.geometry('480x400')
mf.resizable(width=True, height=True)
mf['bg'] = 'white'


label1 = Label(mf, text='Deviner le bon numéro !', fg='Black', bg='white')
label1['font'] = ('Arial', 20)
label1.place(x=85, y=50)

bouton1 = Button(mf, text='Quitter', width=10, height=2, command=mf.destroy)
bouton1.place(x=350, y=300)

chn = StringVar()


entryChn = Entry(mf, textvariable=chn)
entryChn.place(x=180, y=100)


label2 = Label(mf, text='', fg='Red', bg='white')
label2['font'] = ('Arial', 16)
label2.place(x=65, y=150)


def verifier():
    if int(chn.get()) < int(rng):
        label2['text'] = 'Too low'
    elif int(chn.get()) > int(rng):
        label2['text'] = 'Too high'
    else:
        label2['text'] = 'You won !'


def effacer():
    label2['text'] = ''


bouton2 = Button(mf, text='Vérifier', width=10, height=2, command=verifier)
bouton2.place(x=80, y=300)

bouton3 = Button(mf, text='Relancer', width=10, height=2, command=effacer)
bouton3.place(x=215, y=300)

mf.mainloop()
```